# I want to split a string using sscanf in c++. My String will be either "a.b" or "a:b"or "ab" format

Tags: c++, string, split, scanf

```
main()
{
    char *tokenstring = "a.b"; 
    char o[10],s[10];
    sscanf(tokenstring, "%[^'.'].%s", o, s);
    printf("%s\n%s\n ", o, s);
}
```

Output:

```
a
b
```

This is fine. But My input string format varies.

```
string tokenstring = a.b;
```

I am looking for sscaf logic which works for both inputs. a.b or a:b or ab

one more condition. I have chances that my string may not contain either of the delimiters, which means a single value. In that case I want that single value in to some variable. eg: char *tokenstring = "ab";

something similar to `result = sscanf(tokenstring, "%[^':']: or [^'.']. %s", o, s);`

Comment: I don't believe `a b` to be the output when your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: This code is not compiled. Its just rough code. I am more concentrated on the sscanf logic part.

Comment: Please find the compiled code

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <string>
main()
{
   char *tokenstring = "a.b";
   char o[10],s[10];
   sscanf(tokenstring, "%[^'.'].%s", o, s);
   printf("%s\n%s\n ", o, s);   
}

Comment: IMHO you should add `int` before `main` and all those includes into the question. If you include code that compiles, you have better chance someone will *copy and paste* the code into his/her IDE and answer. No offense.

Answer (score 1):

`sscanf` is overkill here, and gives you unreadable code. Just use `std::string::find_first_of(".:")`. Untested code:

```
struct ab {
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
};

ab get_ab(const std::string& str) {
    std::string::size_type pos = str.find_first_of(".:");
    ab res;
    res.a = str.substring(0, pos);
    if (pos != std::string::npos)
        res.b = str.substring(pos + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sscanf` with regexp:

> sscanf(tokenstring, "%[^.:]%*[.:]%s", o, s);

Explanation:

- `%[^.:]` matches all characters that are not `.` or `:`.
- `%*[.:]` matches all characters `.` or `:`. The `*` means the result is not captured into any parameter.
- `%s` matches the rest of the string.

Comment: oops...one more condition. I have chances that my string may not contain either of the delimiters, which means a single value. In that case I want that single value in to some variable. eg: char *tokenstring = "ab";   can i add any reg exp for this condition? Thanks in Advance @ Lukáš Bednařík